# Regex to include +-digit

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex to include all the 4 entries.
I tried this
`^[a-zA-Z+-]+` but it matched only 3 not the SAP+30
The entries are:
`SAP+`,
`SAP+30`,
`C+`,
ABC

Can anybody suggest

Comment: What part of your character group would match on digits?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The match digits, you can use the range `0-9` in the character set (or `\d` on its own). Although from the looks of your examples, you might be better with a more specific regular expression rather than one that matches anything with these characters:

```
^[A-Za-z]+(\+\d*)?$
```

This looks for at least one letter followed by either nothing or one `+` character and then any number of digits.

Comment: I have 2 other data -In transit, 
CFAN R/I can these be matched as well

Comment: This caught the In Transit but not the R/I -> ^[a-zA-Z ]+(\+\d*)?

Comment: What's the pattern for that? Is it just `R/I` or can it be some other letters/symbols/lengths?

Comment: It can be only be letters of any length like RTAS.../ASGHA....